# convert Datetime 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss' to 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, date, datetime

I have a table with column name `[Create_Date] as [Datetime]` (for example = '2016-06-07 07:29:45.290') .

A costumer of mine want this column in a format of `DD\MM\YYYY hh:mm:ss` (For example = '07/06/2016 07:29:45').

I did it by:

```
SELECT  FORMAT ( convert(datetime2(0),create_date), 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss', 'en-US' ) as Record_Date;
```

the problem with this solution, is that the column type Record_Date is [varchar] and I want it in a datetime2(0) format .

Comment: You mean u want to change target field to datetime 2 ?

Comment: yes ! to datetime2(0)/datetime and with the format of 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss'

Answer (score 3):

Date/time values are stored in an internal format.  When you return them, they are returned in the internal format.  The application reading the data then decides how to format the value.

One thing you *can* do is to create a computed column with the value formatted as a string.  If your code works you can do:

```
alter table t
    add create_date_ddmmyyyy as (format( convert(datetime2(0), create_date), 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss', 'en-US' ) );
```

Then you can refer to `create_date_ddmmyyyy` whenever you want the formatted version (I would suggest that it is *only* useful for output).

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question wasn't clear . I do not want to populate the new column "Record_Date" into a table, I need that, the result-set will be in format of 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss' and as a datetime/datetime2(0) data type . 10X